# Excel LOOKUP with multiple outcomes

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

Excel LOOKUP with multiple outcomes

Currently I am using the formula: =LOOKUP("Pending", DK6, A6)

So if the cell contents of DK6 says “Pending” it displays the value from cell A6.

I need to add some more clauses and would appreciate some help on how to construct the formula. The logic I am looking for is as follows…

LOOKUP("Pending", DK6, A6) > ?ELSEIF? > LOOKUP(“Delegated”, DK6, *leave cell blank*) > ?ELSEIF? > LOOKUP(“Rejected”, DK6, *leave cell blank*) > ?ELSEIF? > LOOKUP(*blank cell*, DK6, *leave cell blank*)

Comment: I think maybe I need to use the IFERROR clause with my LOOKUPS but don't seem to be able to contract a formula that works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get lists of multiple matching rows you can apply SMALLL() to pick up the first, second, third, etc. value.

[image]

The formula in DL2 is,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$99, SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$98)+($DK$2:$DK$99<>"Pending")*1E+99,,),ROW(1:1))),"")
  ... or,
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$99, SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$98)+($DK$2:$DK$99<>DL$1)*1E+99,,),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

To gather cells in column A where column DK is blank is a little different.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$99, SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$98)+(($A$2:$A$99="")+($DK$2:$DK$99<>""))*1E+99,,),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

These formulas seem to be a better fit than the array formulas provided in another thread. The values in column A are by nature unique so that does not have to be compensated for.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `ELSEIF` formulas, you need to nest `IF` formulas, for example:

```
=IF(DK6="Pending",A6,IF(DK6="Delegated","",IF(DK6="Rejected","",IF(DK6="",""))))
```

The logic you gave could be simplified because there's *leave cell blank* in last three cases, so you could just use:

=IF(DK6="Pending",A6,"")

Comment: Amazing,thanks that works perfectly!

I've realised there's one more version I need:

IF (DK6 = "Accepted", "Rejected", or "Delegated",A6,"")

What is the correct way to format this?

Comment: `=IF(OR(DK6="Accepted",DK6="Rejected",DK6="Delegated"),A6,"")`

Comment: Having looked at the full code you've provided I've answered my own question. I needed:

=IF(DK6="Accepted", A6, IF(DK6="Rejected", A6, IF(DK6="Delegated", A6,IF(DK6="", ""))))

Comment: Thanks once again, your code is a lot more tidy than my solution.

I wonder if I might ask you a different question. I know this should probably go into a new thread, but you seem like you'll probably know the answer.

I have a VLOOKUP formula as follows:
    =VLOOKUP($C$5,Raw!$A$2:$FJ1000,115,FALSE)

The formula works and displays all the relevant data. However it seems the default value for FALSE is to enter "0". Is there anyway to modify this to say "New"?

Comment: I'm what are you asking about... FALSE as the last parameter of VLOOKUP means that you want exact match. If it doesn't find exact match it returns error. If you want to return "new" in case the formula doesn't find the exact match, you should enclose it with the IFERROR formula.

Comment: Sorry, my explanation wasn't very clear! The current vlookup copies the contents of a cell from another sheet. If this cell is blank it displays a '0'. Rather than showing a '0', I would like it to show 'New'.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm using:

    =IF(ISBLANK(VLOOKUP($C$5,Raw!$A$2:$FJ1000,115,FALSE)), "New", VLOOKUP($C$5,Raw!$A$2:$FJ1000,115,FALSE))

This seems to be doing the trick.