# how to look up in duplicate value

Tags: excel

[image]

I have to have in result "code is 1" and another row with "code is 2" 1 and 2 are 5th column. Only one I have is Q1 - the file is big and the current rows can
 be on different place, columns are same.
It have to work for different files.
The question is when I have duplicate value how to control which match to get.
thank you in advance.

hi this is result what I'm looking for.
Sorry that is not so clear.

the question is : I know only the value in first column. How to get the value from 5th column, when there is Q1 2 times. And I want to control the first, second .. match or if I want only second for example."code is 2". this is example it have to work with more than 2 matches of Q1 in first column.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. I'd like to help but I absolutely do not understand the questions... could precise & reformulate? What have you tried at this point?

Comment: Edit your question to include sample data together with expected results and show what you have tried so far whether it is working or not. See [mcve].

Comment: See [Excel LOOKUP with multiple outcomes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834652/excel-lookup-with-multiple-outcomes/25878607#25878607).